# How to configure Raid10 for 3 disk using iginition in coreos

Tags: linux

Disk:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/md127
```

Link: https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/examples.html#create-a-raid-enabled-data-volume

This config will set up a RAID0 ext4 volume, data, between two separate disks.

Ques: How to configure raid10 for 3 disk?

```
{
  "ignition": { "version": "2.0.0" },
  "storage": {
    "disks": [
      {
        "device": "/dev/sda",
        "wipeTable": true,
        "partitions": [{
          "label": "raid.1.1",
          "number": 1,
          "size": 20480,
          "start": 0
        }]
      },
      {
        "device": "/dev/sdb",
        "wipeTable": true,
        "partitions": [{
          "label": "raid.1.2",
          "number": 1,
          "size": 20480,
          "start": 0
        }]
      }
    ],
    "raid": [{
      "devices": [
        "/dev/disk/by-partlabel/raid.1.1",
        "/dev/disk/by-partlabel/raid.1.2"
      ],
      "level": "stripe",
      "name": "data"
    }],
    "filesystems": [{
      "mount": {
        "device": "/dev/md/data",
        "format": "ext4",
        "create": { "options": [ "-L", "DATA" ] }
      }
    }]
  },
  "systemd": {
    "units": [{
      "name": "var-lib-data.mount",
      "enable": true,
      "contents": "[Mount]\nWhat=/dev/md/data\nWhere=/var/lib/data\nType=ext4\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy=local-fs.target"
    }]
  }
}
```

**I tried using below conf. The os get installed successfully, but during first boot, it get paused in "A start job is running for ignition(disks)"**

```
{
  "ignition": { "version": "2.0.0" },                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  "storage": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    "disks": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      {
        "device": "/dev/sda",                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        "wipeTable": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "partitions": [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          "label": "raid.1.1",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          "number": 1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          "start": 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        }]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      },
      {
        "device": "/dev/sdb",                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        "wipeTable": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "partitions": [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          "label": "raid.1.2",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          "number": 1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          "start": 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        }]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      },
      {
        "device": "/dev/md127",                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        "wipeTable": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "partitions": [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          "label": "raid.1.3",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          "number": 1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          "start": 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        }]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      }
    ],
    "raid": [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      "devices": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        "/dev/disk/by-partlabel/raid.1.1",                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "/dev/disk/by-partlabel/raid.1.2",                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "/dev/disk/by-partlabel/raid.1.3"                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      ],
      "level": "raid10",                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      "name": "data"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }],
    "filesystems": [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      "mount": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        "device": "/dev/md/data",                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        "format": "ext4",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        "create": { "options": [ "-L", "DATA" ] }                                                                                                                                                                                             
      }
    }]
  },
  "systemd": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    "units": [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      "name": "var-lib-data.mount",                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      "enable": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      "contents": "[Mount]\nWhat=/dev/md/data\nWhere=/var/lib/data\nType=ext4\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy=local-fs.target"                                                                                                                         
    }]
  }
}
```

P.S: I am installing coreos with PXEBOOT

```
coreos-install -V current -C beta -c cloud-config.yml -i ignition.yml
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. It's good that you're showing us what you tried. What have you read about RAID? RAID 10 requires at least four disks, because it's RAID 0 above RAID 1. You may want to set up a RAID 01 which is RAID 1 above RAID 0.

Comment: Thanks. :) Wikipedia , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels, says that raid10 with 3 disk is possible.

Comment: Also, the raid0 configuration for 2 disks also get paused on the same error.

Comment: It's pretty irrelevant if something is possible in general. Your whole toolchain must support your non standard configuration (why not use a standard one?). But I can see I got you on the right track since you tried to exclude this as the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Ohk. According to You, which configuration will be best for 3 disk.?

Comment: @Nakshatra *raid10 with 3 disk is possible*  Not really.  The link you provided just describes implementing RAID 10 on three disks by making multiple partitions on the disks and then treating each *partition* as a separate RAID device in the array.  By that definition of "possible", it's "possible" to implement RAID6 - or any RAID level for that matter - on just one disk.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the information. Actually your comment taught me where I was wrong. More over, the coreos support to RAID is limited. Thats why I was getting the same error with normal RAID0 configuration in two disk.